# T-SQL Generate Unique Codes

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a table contacts.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Contacts](
 [ContactId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [ContactCode] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL, --UNIQUE
 [FirstName] [nvarchar](24) NOT NULL,
 [MiddleName] [nvarchar](12) NULL,
 [LastName] [nvarchar](24) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Contacts] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
 [ContactId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

I would like to be able to generate a 10-digit contact code from the stored procedure which should comprise of

```
First Two Digits of FirstName
First Digit of MiddleName(When MiddleName is not blank)
First Two or Three(When MiddleName is Blank) Digits of Last Name
Four digit number starting from zero.
```

Example.

```
John M. Denver = JOMDE-0001
John Denver    = JODEN-0001
John Denver    = JODEN-0002
Bob Dylan      = BODYL-0001
```

Proposed solution could be a function which could be called from inside the stored procedure before saving the values to the table.

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetContactCode
(
 @FirstName nvarchar(24),
 @MiddleName nvarchar(12),
 @LastName nvarchar(24)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
 RETURN('CODE')
END
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Why are you using `nvarchar(10)` if it will always be 10 chars long?

Comment: Because char cannot store a unicode character :).

Comment: Using variable length data types adds a 2 byte overhead per variable length column per row so should be avoided if the data is actually guaranteed to be a particular length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a [RANKING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) clause is one option.

```
;WITH q AS (
  SELECT  ContactID 
          , ContactCode = 
              UPPER(
                SUBSTRING(
                  SUBSTRING(FirstName, 1, 2)
                  + ISNULL(SUBSTRING(MiddleName, 1, 1), '')
                  + SUBSTRING(LastName, 1, 3)
                  , 1, 5)
                + '-')          
  FROM    Contacts
)
SELECT  c.*
        , q.ContactCode 
          + RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 4) 
                  + CAST(
                      RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY q.ContactCode ORDER BY q.ContactID
                    ) AS VARCHAR(4))
                  , 4)
FROM    q INNER JOIN Contacts c ON c.ContactId = q.ContactID
```

Comment: I will check and then get back to you on this. Thank you so much for the kind support.

Comment: Hi Lieven, it looks good and works like a charm. Since the code means to be generated before inserting into the table, could you please wrap the code in the function I mentioned in my question. Thank you.

Comment: @Nick - have you been able to work this out by yourself or is it left open?

Answer (score 1):

This function should do the trick

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetContactCode
(
 @FirstName nvarchar(24),
 @MiddleName nvarchar(12),
 @LastName nvarchar(24)
)
RETURNS nchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
 declare @contactcode nchar(10)

 select top 1 @contactcode = contactCode
 from contacts
 where
  contactcode like left(@FirstName,2)+
    case    
        when @MiddleName is null or @MiddleName = '' then left(@LastName,3) 
        else left(@MiddleName,1)+left(@LastName,2) 
    end+'%'
 order by contactCode desc

    select @Contactcode = 
    Upper(left(@FirstName,2)+
    case    
        when @MiddleName is null or @MiddleName = '' then left(@LastName,3) 
        else left(@MiddleName,1)+left(@LastName,2) 
    end) + '-' + 
    case 
        when @ContactCode is null then'0001' 
        else replace(str(cast(right(@ContactCode,4) as int)+1,4),' ','0') 
    end

    Return @ContactCode

END
```